# Move selection nipple to selected div ID on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website that features many links on the same page:

http://www.alexanderlozada.com

To let the user know what item they are currently viewing, I'd like to implement a small triangle that points at the currently selected item.

example:

[image]

How could I go about doing this without making each link a separate page?

sample of the link I am working with- (I have to keep the current href and rel)

```
<a class="grey show_hide" href="#" rel="#projects" >   
PROJECTS
</a>
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: lol!.. anyone else read this question because of the word `nipple`? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases this is done by using pseudo elements `:before` and/or `:after` like so ([read full article](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/))

CSS:

```
/* creates triangle */
.selected:after {
   content:"";
   display:block; /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
   position:absolute;
   bottom:-2px;
   left:50%;
   width:0;
   margin-left:-10px;
   border-width:0px 15px 15px;
   border-style:solid;
   border-color:white transparent;
} 


div.links {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative; // you must have this to position the triangle propery
    width: 25%;
    height: 45px; // adjust height to fit the menu
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $('div.links').removeClass('selected'); // remove all other 'selected' links
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected'); // sets the current .links to be selected
    });
});
```

Comment: This certainly would create a triangle, but how exactly would it move when different links were clicked?

Comment: @AlexanderLozada Easy peasy, create a class `.selected` and add the css of the triangle. then when you click an element use `$(this).addClass('selected');` (don't forget to `.removeClass('selected')` from all other links)

Comment: Sorry, but could you clarify on that?  Do you mean to change the .triangle-isoceles class in css to .selected, and then call upon it to be created in javascript when I click a link?  How would I go about doing that if I already am executing javascript when clicking the link?  (link html edited into original post).

Comment: @AlexanderLozada updated. now you have everything in the answer. `.selected` class, minor changes to `.links` class and some jQuery. I've tested on your site looks nice. let me know if it did the trick

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks so much for taking the time to pick apart the source HTML and write up some custom code, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an active class in your :

```
<a class="btn active">menu link</a>
```

css:

```
.btn.active { background:url(cursor-active.png) bottom center no-repeat; }
```

js:

```
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $('.btn').removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

You can see here : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FBRt6/1/)

Comment: I've followed your instruction and also created my own image with the correct path - nothing is showing up though.

here is the code that I have:

<div class="links"><a class="btn active grey show_hide" href="#" rel="#projects" >PROJECTS</a></div>

and CSS
.btn.active 
{ 
background:url(img/resource/nipple.png) bottom center no-repeat; 
}

Comment: It certainly looks like a lighter solution, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.  I apologize if I'm making a silly error, but am I putting the javascript in the right spot?  I just added it to the head with the <script type="text/javascript"> tag.  The triangle is appearing under the default active, but is not changing.

Comment: --Fixed, added within a $(function(){ and it seems to work, although the triangle slides to its position.  Probably a conflict in my css.